# SQL Join getting like count of a post

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a table that contains the information of all the posts, table's name is "paylasimlar". and I have another table that contains the information of every like action, table's name is "begeniler". It has 2 columns:

1-User ID of who liked the post 
2-The Post ID that liked

The thing I want to do is to write a query with joins that returns all the information of the posts from table "paylasimlar" with the count of likes it got. The problem I ran into is; if a post hasn't got liked yet there would be no information on the "begeniler" table and it would not return the information of that table as a row. Can someone help?

Comment: can you put some sample data ?

Comment: you need to use left join

Comment: I know but as I mentioned it if a post haven't got any likes it would not appear on result

Comment: do you want the post or not ?

Comment: I want to return all the posts information whether they've got any likes or not. The problem is if a post hasn't got any likes yet it doesn't return the post information

Comment: check my query if you not get result please provide sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.*,count(b.PostID) from paylasimlar a 
left join begeniler b on a.PostID and b.PostID group by b.PostID
```

Comment: Not completely but it lit a bulb in my head